# Page does not show any result

Tags: php, codeigniter, jstree

So I am trying to create a JsTree using the code following and when I try to run the code I dont get any results. The thing is it is the first time I am using JSTrees and also I am quite new in PHP. Any help would be appreciated
This is my view page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Employee Tree</title>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/themes/default/style.min.css" />
<script src="dist/jstree.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){

                //setting to hidden field
                //fill data to tree  with AJAX call

                $('#tree-container').on('changed.jstree', function (e, data) {
                    var i, j, r = [];
                    var state = false;
                    for(i = 0, j = data.selected.length; i < j; i++) {
                        r.push(data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).id);
                    }
                    $('#txttuser').val(r.join(','));
                }).jstree({
                            'plugins': ["wholerow","checkbox"],
                            'core' : {
                                "multiple" : true,
                                'data' : {
                                    "url" : "base_url() ?>tree_controller/getChildren",
                                    "dataType" : "json" // needed only if you do not supply JSON headers
                                }
                            },
                            'checkbox': {
                                three_state: false,
                                cascade: 'up'
                            },
                            'plugins': ["checkbox"]
                        }
                )
            });
</script>


<div class="row">

    <div class="container">


        <input type="hidden" name="node" id="node" value="" />

        <div class="form-group">
            <div id="tree-container"></div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I know you will say this is a pretty noobish question but I really need some help as I have no idea what I am doing here

Comment: There's no PHP code in the question, so the PHP-tag seems a bit redundant. Check your console for any JS errors

Comment: Well I am using php to call this view even though youre correct saying that there is no php in the current code. I wasnt sure whether to put it or not so I will just leave it there just in case @Qirel

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, it appears that one of your issues is with your url

You currently have

```
"url" : "base_url() ?>tree_controller/getChildren",
```

which is an incomplete php statement.

What if you tried...

```
"url" : "<?php echo base_url('tree_controller/getChildren'); ?>",
```

assuming that your $config['base_url'] is correctly set.

You can inspect the code by viewing the generated HTML via your Browser. Look for the "view Source" option when you right click on the webpage.

See how that goes.

Comment: Well as I thought it didn't change anything. I inspected the page and I saw that I am getting an error when I call the js files. apparently in the folder path I have put them they are not recognized and I have no idea which one is the correct path @TimBrownlaw

Comment: And so you would use the same as I have described above for your JS AND CSS Files... use <?php echo base_url();?>

Comment: Yes I did that but I get a 404 error. I tried also with the full  path which gives me a 403 error. I tried changing folder priorities but didnt help. Any idea? @TimBrownlaw

Comment: So you cannot get your JS or CSS loaded at all???? It would help if you provided some details.